# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm creating my web-project on spring mvc, using mysql DB with jpa and hibernate.
I have this type of exception. I had this tables in my DB, but then I had to rebuilt it to set auto-increment in id fields in every table.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jMC.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QZ8R.jpg)

I did all the same (as I thought) actions, now I have those tables:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJnyP.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ixL.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHxH.jpg)
All tables except table "request" work ok, but when I want to add student with request, there is exception: 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    I don't know what does it mean and how to deal with it.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47606290/edit) your question accordingly. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us the code you use to add the student. Maybe you are trying to set an id that the database is expecting to be autogenerated?